# Notification Error When Downloading

Tags: android

I'm using some code from the internet in this - but i still don't know why it's not working...
If i take out the `Notification` things, then it downloads fine (in the background - no good!). But whenever i include them, it forces quit, and i'm not sure why!

**Notification Setup**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListActivity.class);
    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

    // configure the notification
    final Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Downloading Rom via RomGet", System
            .currentTimeMillis());
    notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    notification.contentView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.layout_download);
    notification.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
    notification.contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.status_icon, R.drawable.icon_rom);
    notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.download_description, "Downloading");
    notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.download_progress, 100, 0, false);
    notification.icon = R.drawable.ic_stat_rom;

    final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
            getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(43, notification);
```

**Download Class**

```
    public void run() {         
        try {
            // Setup download things here - all good

            totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

            //create a buffer...
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

            //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
            while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
                downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe

                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
            //close the output stream when done
            fileOutput.close();

        //catch some possible errors...
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // see http://androidsnippets.com/download-an-http-file-to-sdcard-with-progress-notificationØ
    }

    private Handler handler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            //notification.setProgressBar(R.id.download_progress, Math.round(totalSize), Math.round(downloadedSize), false);
            notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.download_description, Integer.toString(downloadedSize));
            // inform the progress bar of updates in progress
            notificationManager.notify(43, notification);
        }
    };
}
```

This is the error it is giving me:

```
05-31 22:48:23.539: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(24431): Shutting down VM
05-31 22:48:23.539: WARN/dalvikvm(24431): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-31 22:48:23.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24431): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-31 22:48:23.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24431): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-31 22:48:23.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24431):     at com.ezeh.romget.ListActivity$DownloadThread$1.handleMessage(ListActivity.java:285)
05-31 22:48:23.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24431):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-31 22:48:23.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24431):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-31 22:48:23.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24431):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
05-31 22:48:23.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24431):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 22:48:23.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24431):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-31 22:48:23.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24431):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
05-31 22:48:23.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24431):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
05-31 22:48:23.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24431):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-31 22:48:23.558: WARN/ActivityManager(13390):   Force finishing activity com.ezeh.romget/.ListActivity
05-31 22:48:24.074: WARN/ActivityManager(13390): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{407e8090 com.ezeh.romget/.ListActivity}
05-31 22:48:29.386: INFO/Process(24431): Sending signal. PID: 24431 SIG: 9
05-31 22:48:29.460: INFO/ActivityManager(13390): Process com.ezeh.romget (pid 24431) has died.
05-31 22:48:29.464: INFO/WindowManager(13390): WIN DEATH: Window{408fbb18 com.ezeh.romget/com.ezeh.romget.ListActivity paused=false}
05-31 22:48:29.468: INFO/DemoService(13809): DiyScheduer.onStart
05-31 22:48:29.468: INFO/ggheart(13809): onStart
05-31 22:48:29.472: INFO/WindowManager(13390): WIN DEATH: Window{40863a78 com.ezeh.romget/com.ezeh.romget.HomeActivity paused=false}
05-31 22:48:29.484: INFO/rxq(13809): onResume()
05-31 22:48:34.644: DEBUG/dalvikvm(24165): GC_EXPLICIT freed 87K, 49% free 3507K/6791K, external 0K/0K, paused 28ms
```

Comment: It would probably help if you included a stack trace.

Comment: I included the LogCat summary. Cheers

Comment: What do you have on line ListActivity.java:285 ? Looks like something is null.

Comment: I realised the problem why it was force quitting, thanks! (i set notifications as final and then initialised them again) Cheers, However, now it simply hangs the whole phone :S it updates the text to about 60k bytes, and then freezes completely. When it unfreezes the file is downloaded fine though... I have no clue xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your new problem with the app freezing while downloading, you are actually blocking the UI process with the download itself.  The way around that is to use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to do the downloading in the background.  Google has an intro to AsyncTasks [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).  There are plenty of other good resources on how to download files in the background online.

Comment: I'm not using async task, but I am running the download in another thread no? I mean, if i don't post any notifications, then the download runs in the background just fine (i just have no visual, i check the file size as it updates in the file browser) How does that work? Is Asynctask better to use rather than another thread? Cheers

Comment: Threads in Android don't really work (the second link I posted explains the problem).  An AsyncTask will stop the app from freezing.

Comment: That sounds awesome, exactly what I need, cheers! Also, what would be the correct way to extend the class if I'm downloading a range of file types? (most of them zip)? I see that `extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>` is being specific about inputting a string (fine), but outputting a bitmap? Or is there something i'm missing? Cheers

Comment: Edit - My mistake, I've read through the other link and i've got that down pat, Cheers!

Comment: You'll likely want to return the file path to the locally saved content, so a String instead of a Bitmap.